# How plausible is the idea of aquatic humans/humanoids having respiration like a frog instead of things like gills?

Tags: science-fiction, evolution, humans, fantasy-races, humanoid

I was reading about frogs, which led me to think: what if, instead of gills, aquatic humanoids had a respiration system like frogs (absorbing the oxygen from the water through their skin)?

Comment: @Tortliena, OP is asking "can a humanoid breath through their skin?" which is not what those other questions are asking.

Comment: @L.Dutch Seems like christmas diner yesterday is still weighing down my sore eyes :p.

Answer (score 3):

It would be hard to achieve for a humanoid the size of a human. Consider that the exchange surface of human lungs, thanks to the alveoli, is about 100 square meters, which is way larger than the surface of the skin.

For a frog sized and cold blooded creature it works because:

- smaller animals have a relatively large skin surface with respect to their body volume
- cold blooded animal have lower metabolic needs and thus lower oxygen need

Comment: What if they were either cold blooded or mesothermic?

Comment: @CJ: Do not underestimate the total surface area of the gills of fish; see Nicholas C. Wegner *et al.*, "[Gill Morphometrics in Relation to Gas Transfer and Ram Ventilation in High-Energy Demand Teleosts: Scombrids and Billfishes](https://www.pier.org/userdocs/images/files/scientific_publications/Wegner%20et%20al.%202010.pdf)", *Journal of Morphology* 271:36–49 (2010), for some numbers. It is not small. You may want to look at what [giant salamanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_salamander), not known for their active lifestyles, have to do to increase the area of their skin.

Comment: What about if these humanoids were phenomenally wrinkly?  They make those Shar-Pei dogs look like billiard balls, they are so wrinkly.  A huge surface area of redundant floppy skin.  How about then?

Comment: I mean so wrinkly that raisins say "Holy moly, what happened to _you_?"

Answer (score 1):

It may be plausible assuming you can increase the surface area of the skin and your aquatic humanoids are cold-blooded, as @L.Dutch pointed out. But there are some important limitations of frog physiology to consider:

1. Frogs can only absorb oxygen through their skin if their skin is moist. An aquatic humanoid would be unable to absorb oxygen through their skin when on land, once their skin dries up. Although this is a nonissue if they also have a set of normal lungs and respiration tract (as mermaids do).
2. Frogs use their skin to absorb oxygen from underwater. If there’s not enough oxygen in the water, your aquatic humanoid would drown. Oxygen is generally low at higher depths. Also algae settles to the bottom of the sea and can cause oxygen depletion when it decomposes. It doesn’t make for a great setting if your aquatic humanoids can’t swim among algae on the seabeds.
3. Frogs can’t live in saltwater. The high salt content can clog a frog’s blood cells and lead to dehydration. If you want your aquatic humanoids to survive in saltwater, having pores that can absorb water may not be the best method.